# How to insert names into a database without leaving page and displaying multiple forms on the submission page

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am new to php and ajax and have attempted to find a a solution to my challenge.
Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

I have multiple forms each with a name value. I need to click Submit on each form and insert the name into the database mytable by calling insert.php

Each time I click Submit on any form the name inseertd  is always the name from the first form "tommy"

Also the message "Registration Successfully" displays on each form.

So my challenge is to only insert the name from the form being submitted.

I would also like to change the form button text from "Insert" to "Inserted" after the successful insert.

**forms.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#name").val();
var dataString = 'name='+ name;

if(name=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "insert.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>

<form method="post" name="form">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="harry"/>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Insert" class="submit"/>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</div>
</form>

<form method="post" name="form">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="tommy"/>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Insert" class="submit"/>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</div>
</form>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mydbase`.`mytable` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$name')");
}else { echo 'Failed'; }
```

?>

Comment: What is error  you get ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the form which is submitted.

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this).parents('form')[0];
  var name = $(form).find('input#name').val();
  ...
});
```

To show your messages:

```
$(form).find('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$(form).find('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
```

Comment: Could you explain how I give the submitted form an id please

Comment: If you want to give the forms an id, you just add the id in the template. It doesn't seems necessary to me to do it afterwards. And you might get issues when both buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Return 1 from your insert.php file and check in the ajax response.and write code according to the response.
Please check the code.

Fell free to ask anything.

:)


<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".submit").click(function() {
var name = $("#name").val();
var dataString = 'name='+ name;

if(name=='')
{
$('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
}
else
{
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "insert.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(data){
$('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
$('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();

/****/
if(data == 1)
{
    $('.msg').text("sucess msg");
    //also change buttin text with jquery 
}
else{
    $('.msg').text("fail msg");

}
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>

<form method="post" name="form">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="harry"/>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Insert" class="submit"/>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</div>
</form>

<form method="post" name="form">
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="tommy"/>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Insert" class="submit"/>
<span class="error" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
<span class="success" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</div>
</form>
</div class = "msg"></div>

<?php
if($_POST)
{
$name=$_POST['name'];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mydbase`.`mytable` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, '$name')");`enter code here`
return 1;
}else { echo 'Failed'; }
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain what code I place at: `enter code here`